# Meta top bar text color inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed on Meta.UX the user's rep and badge count (and the mod diamond) aren't in the standard "link color" like the other top bar links. Compare the main site to the meta site and you'll see:

Balanced quietness:
[image]
Suddenly white text un-quietness:
[image]

Keeping the links the same color keeps a nice consistency; could we get the colors of the meta top bar consistent like the Main top bar?

Answer (score 1):

The colors are not actually the same, but the impression of them with that background makes them look very similar. Maybe a more similar color on counters would be preferable?

[image]

Comment: Well not value-to-value the same, but it's light blue vs sky blue. I'd be fine with two shades of yellow for Meta, but the white to yellow contrast is too sharp

Comment: @BenBrocka I totally agree on that. I'd like a little darker yellow than the <name> yellow.

Comment: @BennySkogberg worth noting perhaps that the current contrast between the yellow foreground text and grey background _already_ fails WCAG contrast requirements (admittedly only by a little); a darker yellow would fail by more.